# How can I show Month View in smartgwt Calendar?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I want to show only Month view of Calendar in SmartGWT2.0 with Eclipse 3.5(Galilio)
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

setShowDayView(false)
setShowWeekView(false)

Sample here:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#compact_calendar_category